# Compressed Histogram of Gradients (CHoG)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am trying to understand the implementation of low bitrate descriptor  Compressed Histogram of Gradients (CHoG) from Stanford Mobile Visual Search publication. Is there any open-source code available in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I contacted the Authors of CHoG they say its a copyrighted code.

Comment: This does not mean one can not implement one's own, open source, version of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OpenCV has an implementation of [Compressed HOG](http://www.stanford.edu/~dmchen/mvs.html). However, OpenCV does provide the traditional HOG implementation from the [Dalal-Triggs 2005 paper](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf).

Here's how to use OpenCV's `HOGDescriptor`, with the default parameters from the Dalal-Triggs paper:

```
cv::HOGDescriptor d();
vector<float> descriptorsValues; //this is the useful output
vector<cv::Point> locations;
d.compute(img, descriptorsValues, cv::Size(0,0), cv::Size(0,0), locations);
```

If you want to customize the HOG setup, you can use the `HOGDescriptor` constructor that takes custom parameters:

```
cv::HOGDescriptor d(win_size, block_size, block_stride, cell_size, nOri, 1, -1, cv::HOGDescriptor::L2Hys, 0.2, gamma_corr, nLevels);
```

There's also a [GPU version](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor) of `HOGDescriptor` in OpenCV.

Comment: Actually I contacted the Authors of CHoG they say its a copyrighted code. Thanks for the tip on HoG.